# Why do you invert columns in Gauss elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to solve a system of equations using Gauss elimination method. I have several questions regarding this technique. Below is an example of a system of equations, together with the solution.

Why are the columns C2 and C4 inverted at the end? Why can't we write the equivalent system without any inversion of columns? The matrix before inverting is in trapezoidal form, as it should.

[image]

Comment: There is no need to invert. It was done probably just for visual convenience: placing the pivot elements in front of the matrix, so you can see what the leading variables are ($x_1$ and $x_4$, in this case). But personally I find it unnecessary. (Note: my comment is in the context of doing simple computations and matrix elimination. In numerical linear algebra, such as designing algorithms, it might be useful to do such inversions. I don't know.)